# How to INSERT into a table using a const VALUE and SELECT items from another table

Tags: mysql

I want to INSERT some columns from a table and also INSERT a const VALUE that I have established.

```
"INSERT INTO Requests (category, item, brand, sku, price, memberName) SELECT Category, Model, Make, Sku, Price FROM Catalog WHERE id = ? VALUES (?)";
```

Where memberName is the const from req.body.memberId;
WHERE id = ? , is the id of the Catalog item I am selecting.

Answer (score 0):

Put the parameter marker into the `SELECT` in the position of the column to be assigned:

```
INSERT INTO Requests (category, item, brand, sku, price, memberName)
SELECT Category, Model, Make, Sku, Price, ? FROM Catalog WHERE id = ?
```

Note that the value you want in the table has to be the *first* parameter into the prepared query, and the primary key the second.

Comment: Thank you, That solved my issue.